# What is the error in syntax, Why Non-active player gets points counted

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am building a simple dice game. I am having an issue with the score counting on the player that is not active. When it switches players it still counts for the player that is not active. I have looked over it a lot and I just can't find it. I even took a little break and moved a little ahead and came back and still could not find it.  Here is my code.

```
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer;

scores = [0, 0];
roundScore = 0;
activePlayer = 1;

document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
document.getElementById('score-1').textContent = '0';
document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function 
() {

//ran. number
var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

//    displaying result
var diceDom = document.querySelector('.dice');
diceDom.style.display = 'block';
diceDom.src = 'Assets/dice-' + dice + '.png';

//    update round score IF the rolled # was not a 1
if (dice !== 1) {
    roundScore += dice;
    document.querySelector('#current-' + activePlayer).textContent = 
roundScore;
} else {
    //go to next player
    nextPlayer();
}

});


document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click', function() 
{
// add current score to global
scores[activePlayer] += roundScore;
//update UI
document.querySelector('#score-' + activePlayer).textContent = 
scores[activePlayer];
//check if player won the game


//next player
nextPlayer();
});

function nextPlayer() {
//go to next player
    activePlayer === 0 ? activePlayer = 1 : activePlayer = 0;
    roundScore = 0;

    document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';

    document.querySelector('.player-0- 
    panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-1- 
  panel').classList.toggle('active');
    //hide dice when player rolls 1
    document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
 }
```

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). -- Create a working sample that demonstrates the problem. Include everything required, including the html. -- It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem.

Comment: Also, in `function nextPlayer()` there are some odd line-breaks in `player-0- ... panel` and `player-1- ... panel`.